# Fade in text with jQuery appearing choppy, displacing each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

Example here:

https://codepen.io/rfehre/pen/LrZVre

So I'm trying to fade in 'we' 'put' 'in' and 'work' sequentially. As it stands right now 'we' 'put' and 'in' come in very choppy and displace one another rather than fading into their final spots right off the bat.

I'm using .delay and fading in from a 'display:none' as it stands right now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hidden1').delay(400).fadeIn(1000);
    $('.hidden2').delay(800).fadeIn(1000);

   $('.hidden3').delay(1200).fadeIn(1000);

   $('.hidden4').delay(1600).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `display: none` use `opacity: 0`, and instead of `.fadeIn(1000)` use `.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000)`.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKEyBJ

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: This is a much better (and easier/cleaner) answer. Nice one!

Comment: I won't submit this as answer because the effect is different, but, just to keep in mind: you could use the callback function of 'animate' method, like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxKdLW

Comment: ...Also, in order to add an explanation to this (good) answer: With `display:none` elements doesn't take space, but with `opacity:0`, they do take space, that's why you notice it as "choopy" and "displaced", beacuse invisible words weren't occupying space and text was centered. If text was left-aligned, you wouldn't notice any difference.